# Mixing classmethod and staticmethod in a class hierarchy

Tags: python

I have a class hierarchy where the base class `Base` have a method `foo` defined as a `classmethod`. However `Base`, does not use the `cls` argument at all.

It is only defined as such for consistence with `Derived`, which uses `cls`.

My question is: Does it make sense to define `foo` as a `staticmethod` in `Base`, and in `Derived` define `foo` as a `classmethod`?

I understand the argument about consistency across the entire hierarchy. But the author of `Base` might not know what is needed by subclasses. In this way, the code is self-contained.

Comment: This depends entirely on what the method is for. If `Base.foo` truly does not need the class argument, I'm having trouble picture a legitimate reason why `Derived.foo` would.

Comment: What about the other way around: `Base` uses the class argument, whereas `Derived` doesn't? For example, if I have a base class where I do something useful, but in a particular subset of the instances I want to nullify this behaviour. Honestly, the reason why this question popped up is because we're raising `NotImplemented` in `Base` (instead of decorating the methods with `abc.abstractmethod`).